# How can I destroy all OSGi blueprint components before the OSGi framework is stopped?

Tags: java, osgi, blueprint-osgi

If I stop the OSGi framework, the OSGi blueprint components are not destroyed (destroy methods are not called). Why is this the case and how can I destroy them. I have my own OSGi launcher implementation. I'm using a shutdown hook and then stop the OSGi framework:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Launcher.logService.log(LogService.LOG_WARNING, "HANDLE SHUTDOWN");
        if(Launcher.framework != null) {
            try {
                Launcher.framework.stop();
            } catch (BundleException e) {
                Launcher.logService.log(LogService.LOG_ERROR, "Shutdown" + ((Launcher.framework != null) ? " of " + Launcher.framework.getSymbolicName() + " " : " ") + "failed!", e);
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should wait for the framework to stop.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Launcher.logService.log(LogService.LOG_WARNING, "HANDLE SHUTDOWN");
        if(Launcher.framework != null) {
            try {
                Launcher.framework.stop();
                Launcher.framework.waitForStop(0); // !!!
            } catch (BundleException e) {
                Launcher.logService.log(LogService.LOG_ERROR, "Shutdown" + ((Launcher.framework != null) ? " of " + Launcher.framework.getSymbolicName() + " " : " ") + "failed!", e);
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
});
```